# Query VSTS for all PBI's with no open tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to be able to create a query in VSTS that will return a list of PBI's (from a specific sprint/area) where all tasks are "Done".

It this possible? From what I can see around SO this requires using the REST API of VSTS.

Would I be able to create a chart in a dashboard with a hierarchy list?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you mean get the list of PBIs only when all the tasks belongs to each PBI are done (and  for a certain sprint)? It's impossible to achieve that by WIT query , but you can developer your own extension to show the specified PBIs in dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this, although you will also get the tasks returned, but you should be able to easily filter those out depending on what you are trying to do.

Use the following Steps:

1. Queries -> New Query
2. Type of query -> Work Items and Direct Links
3. Filters for top level work items -> set this to the type of work items you are using, in my example I am using 'User Story'. Add additional path/iteration filters that you require
4. Filters for linked work items -> Set work Item Type = Task and State = Closed
5. Filter Options -> Only Return Items that have matching links

[image]

Comment: I don't think is answer is correct (anymore). Maybe Azure DevOps changed, but for me your query returns PBIs with tasks that are not done (only it does not show the tasks in the query). See my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858200/query-azure-devops-for-all-items-with-no-open-children