# Adding a Link to a work item breaks my query

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to use VSTS work item management with as few modifications as possible. One of the requirements we have is that our QA department needs to be able to find out which PBIs and Bugs are ready for them to start working.

(we are using our own inherited process based on the built-in SCRUM template)

Our definition of "ready for QA" is that - for e.g. a PBI - all non-QA tasks are done.

I have created this board:

[image: SCRUM board]

In this case we should be able to make a list (query) that would result in these PBI's and Bugs:

- 5101 Demo - Ready for QA
- 4970 Demo - Ready for QA
- 8542 Bug - Ready for QA

I have made a query that does that (I got help [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955787/query-vsts-for-all-pbis-with-no-open-tasks))

[image: VSTS query]

**PROBLEM:**

So until we actually started onboarding QA resources, everything was bliss.

However - we have found out that if we make a "link" to PBI's and Bugs they disappear from the result. We need our QA-resources to create a link from their Test cases to the PBI's and bugs and such the query I have does not work anymore.

But - I cannot ... for the love of God ... figure out how to modify my query to enable this. *Any* references break my query - even between a PBI and a Bug.

What do I do with this?

**Problem walk-through:**

Before adding references to either PBIs or Bugs the query looks like this:

[image: VSTS Query result when all is good]

The query returns two PBIs and one Bug.

Then I add a "Related" link from a Test case to the Bug:

[image: Adding a link from a Test case to a Bug]

The query now has this result:

[image: Result of query after adding link]

**Solution found:**

The result of the query after the solution proposed by Marina is this:

[image: Solution of the problem]

Comment: What's the link did you add to PBI and Bug work items? Can you share a screen shot for a PBI/Bug which add link and disappear from the query?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I have updated the question with the details you requested :-). Thanks for reaching out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `Work Item Type <> Test case` in the linked work item clauses and group the existing clauses:

[image]

Comment: It works, @marina . Thank you! I need to get feedback from our QA department to get verification that it solves their requirement.