# Query Azure DevOps for all items with no open children

Tags: azure-devops

What I want to accomplish is an overview of PBIs that are not marked as done, but all the tasks of them are done (so that the PBI should be marked as done as well).

This is similar to this item: [Query VSTS for all PBI's with no open tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955787/query-vsts-for-all-pbis-with-no-open-tasks), except the answer is incorrect (because it does not check if **all** items are done, it only returns the items that are done).

[image: screenshot of query]
This does return all PBIs who's tasks are marked done, but also PBIs that don't have tasks and only a parent.

Is it even possible to make such a query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I let it be and just use it as I had it in my question. I marked his answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, work item queries do not support that. I think, that work maybe done with Power BI Reports: [Connect to Analytics with Power BI Data Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it too complex. If your User Stories only link to one Parent Item, then try this query.

[image: my query parameters]

In my case it worked well.