# Filter UserStories by number of related Tasks

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

In DevOps we need to have a query for all UserStories that have exectly one childed Task that is not closed.

All our UserStories have different Tasks as children. We need to know if there are UserStories with an arbitrary number of Tasks, that has exactly one of the Tasks left, that is not closed. Is there a posibility to do so?

I have alreade read the question of [Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955787/query-vsts-for-all-pbis-with-no-open-tasks). With the solution given there I achieved to select all userstries that have tasks that are opened:
[image]

But I don't know how to filter the UserStory by the number of the Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Related Link Count` to filter the workitems by the number of its related links. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/linking-attachments?view=azure-devops) for more information.

[image].

You have to be careful when using `Related Link Count` filter. Because as it is stated in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#work-link-types)

> **a work item's Related Link Count corresponds to the sum of all links defined with a work link type**.

So if your user stories only have Tasks as child, above `Related Link Count` filter works without problem.

But if the user story also has another child that is of other work item types than Task. This child link will be counted too. And this will cause the `Related Link Count` fail to filter out this user story.

A workaround for above scenario might be to set `Related Link Count > 0`. By default, those user stories with only one child task will be listed at the end of the result. So that you can easily get those user stories. You can also export the query result to CSV file and filter those user stories manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this solution is, that `Related Link Count` uses all links. The restrictions given on the below section does not influence the number of items counted for `Related Link Count`. So your query finds all UserStories with exactly one  Task and this Task is not closed. I am looking for a query that finds all userStories with an arbetrary number of Tasks where exactly one is not closed.

Comment: I am afraid there is not a query that can achieve this. You can set `Related Link Count > 0`. And you will find those user stories which you are trying to query are listed at the end of the query result.